# Observable of array to array (Rxjs)

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have a service and its `getAllMessages()` returns an observable of an array of items : `Observable<ITEM[]>`

I map the result like this to post each ITEM to a RestAPI :

```
this.service.getAllMessages()
.map(items => ...for each item of items, call this.apiService.postMessage(item)...)
```

`postMessage(item)` returns an `Observable<Response>`

My goal is to get an `Observable<Response[]>` for which I can check the http code of every post from `this.apiService.postMessage(item)`

I tried using `flatMap` :

```
this.service.getAllMessages()
  .flatMap(items => {
    return items.map(item => {
      return this.apiService.postMessage(item);
    });
  }).subscribe(RES => {
    console.log(RES);
  });
```

but here RES is an `Observable<Response>` and not a simple `Response`

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is returned by your `this.service.getAllMessages()` is an array of `Observable`, not an `Observable` of array. The `.map()` function belongs to the function of array.

If you want to execute all the Observables in parallel, use `.forkJoin()`:

```
this.service.getAllMessages()
    .flatMap(items => {
        return Observable.forkJoin(items.map(item => this.apiService.postMessage(item)));
    })
    .subscribe(RES => {
        console.log(RES);
    });
```

If you want to execute the observables in sequential, use `.concat()`:

```
this.service.getAllMessages()
    .flatMap(items => {
        return Observable.concat(...items.map(item => this.apiService.postMessage(item)));
    })
    .subscribe(RES => {
        console.log(RES);
    });
```

*Note the spread operator for `.concat`.*

Comment: Thanks a lot you saved my day ! (didnt know about the spread operator, happy to learn)